# Como abrir arquivos .fxml do NetBeans diretamente no Scene Builder?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Quando clico sobre o arquivo de extensão fxml o Scene Builder não abre para que eu possa trabalhar em cima do mesmo. O que posso fazer?

Comment: Já configurou o netbeans para que ele abra arquivos fxml no scene builder?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/sb-with-nb.htm

Answer (score 1):

Se você instalou o Scene Builder antes do NetBeans, não é preciso fazer nada, o instalador fará o trabalho de configurar tudo automaticamente (assim como faz com o JDK).

Se você instalou o Scene Builder após o NetBeans, é preciso acessar as configurações do IDE e definir a Home page manualmente, do contrário ele não reconhecerá os arquivos .fxml de serem abertos no programa. Vá em "Ferramentas" > "Opções" no menu superior e configure o JavaFX:

<kbd>[image: netbeans, configuração do javafx]</kbd>